# How can I update all Snap packages?

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I know that I can update a snap package using

```
sudo snap refresh <package>
```

But is there a way to update all snaps, like

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 637, accepted):

```
sudo snap refresh
```

Will do this. It is part of `snapd` 2.0.8, which landed 2016-06-13 in `xenial-updates`.

```
snap refresh --list
```

Only lists the updates without refreshing the packages.

```
snap info <snap name>
```

Can show which versions are available for a particular package.

---

You can also update a specific application if the other method fails

```
sudo snap refresh <Application>
```

Example usage:

```
sudo snap refresh slack --classic
```

Comment: You need to do `sudo snap refresh`

Comment: @Boris, `snap` prompts you for your password if you don't include `sudo` so it's not entirely necessary.

Comment: @SpookyGengar no it doesn't:
$ snap refresh
error: access denied (try with sudo)

Comment: @RickyNelson On my 18.04 it does prompt me without using `sudo`

Comment: @SpookyGengar @John I'm on Ubuntu 19.10 with `snapd` 2.43.3 and it doesn't prompt me, it just says `error: access denied (try with sudo)`.

Comment: My 20.04 gives the error instead of prompting for password.

Comment: snap refresh without sudo gives in german Autorisierung aus irgendeinem Grund fehlgeschlagen after entering the password.With sudo all fine.

Comment: as of ubuntu 21.10, running `snap refresh` does pop up a gui dialog asking for admin (root) password; so, if people are not seeing this, perhaps it's because they're not in a graphical (GUI) desktop environment? Using `sudo` in a headless env (eg docker, ssh,etc) would be equivalent.

Comment: I would rather reference another answer in this thread as well. it is sometimes necessary to first kill the Application and then do the update:
'sudo killall <Application>'

Comment: ```Sudo snap refresh``` didn't update all my snap packages. it showed ````all snap are up to date``` . I had to specifically do ```snap refresh <packageName>``` to update a specific package

Answer (score 72):

According to [Snap tutorial](https://snapcraft.io/docs/getting-started#heading--refreshing) Snaps are automatically updated in the background once per day.

However, if you don't close the application it will not be updated and you will receive daily notifications to do so.

Comment: However, I was checking Firefox today which said "Updates disabled by your system administrator" (strange since I am the only user and I just installed my OS three days ago). `snap refresh firefox` was the only way to get the latest security patches.

Comment: Interesting. Please add a comment if you ever find out why that's the case...

Comment: However, if you don't close the application it will not be updated and you will receive daily notifications to do so.

Comment: Still can't fix that annoying update issue. we're 5 years later (or 1 depending on the comment). snap has been rolled out to mayer public distro's, and i still have to update in 3 places and close apps. once that was the big selling point of linux upgrading without closing (rebooting).

Answer (score 29):

Generally, you don't need to do anything.

snapd, in Ubuntu installs, will automatically check for updates several times each day. That's a key feature of snaps.

- Exception: Applications cannot be updated while running, which means that long-lived applications (like web browsers) might not update automatically. In Ubuntu 22.04 and newer releases, snapd will warn you daily about your 2-week window to quit, update, and restart.

Here's how to determine how often snapd will automatically check for updates:  ([source](https://snapcraft.io/docs/keeping-snaps-up-to-date))

```
$ snap refresh --time
timer: 00:00~24:00/4        <------ "/4" means refresh every 4 hours.
last: today at 17:15 CDT
next: today at 21:45 CDT
```

Comment: My `next` is seven days ago. Should I be bothered? My timer is the same as yours, but in the source link there is the info refresh 4 times a day, which is every 6 hours.So if my Pc is never on for 6 hours, I will never get an update. So I have to change the config..

Comment: @Timo please open a new question if your issue persists. We're not going to diagnose that underlying cause of your symptom here.

Answer (score 16):

For me the issue was with snap store. It booted on start hence it could never update itself.

so I ran to verify that snap-store is the issue

```
 sudo snap refresh 
 snap refresh --list
 snap refresh --time
```

The fix was to kill the process and then update:

```
 sudo killall snap-store
 sudo snap refresh
```

Comment: this one worked for me

Comment: killing the snap-store and then doing a refresh also helped me. My pc is not on very long as a home PC, so the snaps don't always get time to update, I think.

Answer (score 12):

Try running `snap` with `sudo`:

```
sudo snap refresh
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this in `/usr/bin/update-snaps`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
ROOT_UID="0"

#Check if run as root
if [ "$UID" -ne "$ROOT_UID" ] ; then
        echo "You must be root to do that!"
        exit 1
fi

snap list | awk -F" " '{if ($1 && NR>1) { system("snap refresh " $1 " 2>/dev/null") }}'
```

Comment: This is not necessary any more.

Answer (score 2):

### Updates the Snap packages

If what we want is to check if there is an update of an app and install it, the command will be the following, where APPLICATION corresponds to the program we want to update:

```
sudo snap refresh APPLICATION
```

For example, if we want update Firefox, the command would be `sudo snap refresh firefox`.

What I and maybe some of you are wondering is: "Who updates only one package from the terminal?" Surely someone will, but I usually update everything. The Snap equivalent of `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, Is the following:

By not indicating any package, what it will do is search for all the Snaps that we have installed, it will check if there is a new version and it will install it.

### List updates without installing them

The third command I was talking about may be interesting if you only want to install some packages. It would be the following:

This can help us, for example, if we are waiting for an update like May water, we see that it is and then we want to install the app we expected and some other, avoiding installing everything if it turns out that there is a lot to install. In this way, we would save time. In [this article](https://ubunlog.com/en/manage-packages-snap-ubuntu-16-04/) you have other options that we can use with the «snap» command.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way that worked for me was to go to the search bar and search for snap store, open that up, go to the update tab, then press update.

Answer (score 2):

What I did it was: In terminal (ubuntu 22.10)

```
~$ snap-store
```

You get

[image]

And that is all

Answer (score 1):

With Slack (and some other apps) it's a little more tricky because they run in the background and start automatically on reboot. Be sure to close the app in the background and ensure that it has not started automatically on reboot if you wish to update. Here's a command to stop slack as an example of such a program:

`sudo kill -9 $(pidof slack)`

After that you can run the update of the specific app:

`sudo snap refresh slack --classic`

to have it take effect.

Here's a handy copy and paste one-liner:

`sudo kill -9 $(pidof slack);sudo snap refresh slack --classic`

Might even put that in a shutdown script to fully automate.