# What are the differences between snaps, appimage, flatpak and others?

Tags: snap, appimage, flatpak

I have been getting this question lately from students and although I have a lot of information to offer, I have not found a source that I can point people to where they can read an update answer (I have found a lot of misinformation and obsolete information). So, some of the questions I have for package formats like snap, appimage, flatpak and others in this evolution of universal packaging systems are:

- Who created the package format?
- What features does it offer?
- What features are unique to it? (That the others do not yet have)
- Who supports it?
- What Distributions use it?
- What focus does the package have? (For Desktop, Clouds, Mobile, etc..)
- Which are more actively developed?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Here is a long tabular comparison of AppImage vs. Snap vs. Flatpak features. It is from the [AppImage Wiki on GitHub](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/Similar-projects#comparison):

- https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/Similar-projects#comparison

*Note that this comparison is mainly from the perspective of AppImage, although it tries to represent each project fairly.*

#### General

| **Feature** | **AppImage** | **Snap** | **Flatpak** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Package desktop GUI apps | ✅ Yes | ✅ Yes | ✅ Yes |
| Package terminal CLI tools | ✅ Yes | ✅ Yes | ✅ Yes (with App ID aliases if you edit PATH)[[1](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/releases/tag/0.10.2)] |
| Package server processes | ✅ Yes | ✅ Yes | ⚠️ Possible but not main goal [[1](https://flatpak.org/faq/#Can_Flatpak_be_used_on_servers_too_)] |
| Package system services | ❌ No | ✅ Yes [[1](https://snapcraft.io/pulseaudio)] | ❌ No |
| Package kernels | ❌ No | ✅ Yes [[1](https://snapcraft.io/pi2-kernel)] | ❌ No |
| Correct Application Theming | ✅ Yes (if done correctly) | ✅ Yes (if the current system theme has been Snapped) [[1](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/06/change-snap-app-theme)] | ✅ Yes (if current system theme has been Flatpak'ed) [[1](https://youtu.be/gJVKypMwJYI?t=6m20s)] [[2](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/flatpak-theme-issue-fix)] [[3](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/114)] |
| Using libraries and dependencies | From base system or bundled with appimage | From base system, [base snap](https://snapcraft.io/docs/base-snaps), platform snap ([KDE](https://snapcraft.io/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18), [GNOME](https://snapcraft.io/gnome-3-34-1804), [Wine](https://snapcraft.io/wine-platform-5-stable), ..) or bundled with Snap | From Freedesktop, GNOME, KDE main [runtimes](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/available-runtimes.html) or bundled with Flatpak |
| Corporate backing | ❌ No (Community project) | ✅ Yes (Canonical) | ✅ Yes (Endless, Red Hat) |

#### Adoption

| **Feature** | **AppImage** | **Snap** | **Flatpak** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Number of applications in main store | 1126 (2020-08-14 [[1](https://appimage.github.io/apps/)] [history](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/AppImages)) | +6400 (2020-08-06 [[1](https://ubuntu.com/blog/infographic-ubuntu-from-2004-to-20-04-lts)]) | ~1100 (2020-08-14) |
| Brand-name commercial application vendors using the format | [Adobe](https://github.com/adobe/cryptr), [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/ibm-db2-direct-and-developer-editions), [KDAB](https://github.com/KDAB/hotspot/releases), [Microsoft](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases), [Prusa](https://prusacontrol.org/), [Ultimaker](https://ultimaker.com/en/products/ultimaker-cura), ... | [Microsoft](https://snapcraft.io/azure-cli), [Spotify](https://snapcraft.io/spotify), [Slack](https://snapcraft.io/slack), [JetBrains](https://snapcraft.io/search?category=&q=jetbrains), [Skype](https://snapcraft.io/skype), [nodesource](https://snapcraft.io/node), ... | [Xamarin](https://download.mono-project.com/repo/monodevelop.flatpakref), Codethink, Igalia, ... |
| Built into third-party application development tools | electron-builder | electron-builder, GNOME Builder | GNOME Builder |

#### Usability

**AppImage**

Download from site, then drag-and-drop a single file in the file manager to desired installation location.

[image: drag-and-drop]

**Snap**

Install via distribution app store (supported out of the box on Ubuntu, Zorin OS, KDE Neon, ..) or via CLI:

```
$ snap install gimp
```

**Flatpak**

Install via distribution app store (supported out of the box on Fedora, EndlessOS, ..) or via CLI:

```
$ flatpak install --user flathub org.gimp.GIMP
```

#### Sandboxing / Confinement

| **Feature** | **AppImage** | **Snap** | **Flatpak** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Can run without sandboxing | ✅ Yes (Not required. Optional to the packager.) | ✅ Yes (if snap was built and approved to use 'classic' confinement) [[1](https://docs.snapcraft.io/reference/confinement)] [[2](https://youtu.be/WQ9LSZ7_6QM?t=1h10m52s)] | ❌ No (Limiting application access's by design) |
| Can be used with different sandboxes | ✅ Yes (e.g. [Firejail](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail) [[1](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/appimage-support/)], AppArmor [[2](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/commit/1738bbf7181d6c3b6d9f82bfa5b3f6d21ad503c3)], [Bubblewrap](https://github.com/projectatomic/bubblewrap)) | ❌ No (is tightly coupled to [AppArmor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor)) | ❌ No (is tightly coupled to [Bubblewrap](https://github.com/projectatomic/bubblewrap)) |

#### Application Installation / Execution

| **Feature** | **AppImage** | **Snap** | **Flatpak** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Can run without installation | ✅ Yes (after setting the executable bit) | ❌ No (needs to be installed by snapd) | ❌ No (needs to be installed by Flatpak client-side tools) |
| Can run without root access | ✅ Yes | ⚠️ Only after installation | ⚠️ Only after installation |
| Run from compressed source without unpacking | ✅ Yes | ✅ Yes | ❌ No |
| Application authors can place downloadable file next to .exe (Windows) and .dmg (macOS) which users can install on offline systems | ✅ Yes (.appimage - contains all that is needed to run the application on an offline system) | ❌ No (.snap - requires snapd to be installed and the system must be online if additional snaps are required) | ❌ No (.flatpakref files require Internet, .flatpak bundles require a runtime to be installed) |
| Allows application authors to self-host application with no functionality loss | ✅ Yes | ❌ No | ✅ Yes [[1](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/hosting-a-repository.html)] |
| Suitable/optimized for air-gapped (offline) machines (the kind Ed Snowden uses) | ✅ Yes | ✅ Yes (You can side-load apps and updates offline) | ✅ Yes (P2P support allows offline installs and updates) |
| Can store and run applications from non-standard locations such as network shares, CD-ROM, etc. | ✅ Yes | tbd | ✅ Yes (requires configuration) [[1](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html#flatpak-installation)] |

#### Application Distribution

| **Feature** | **AppImage** | **Snap** | **Flatpak** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Central Repo / Directory | [AppImageHub](https://appimage.github.io/apps/) | [Snap Store](https://uappexplorer.com/snaps) | [FlatHub](https://flathub.org/apps.html) |
| Fully decentralized without central gatekeepers | ✅ Yes | ❌ No (one dominant app store) [[1](https://medium.com/@uriadonayherrera/nitrux-appimage-52937e286edc)] | ✅ Yes |
| Individual App Repositories | ❌ No (not stored in repositories) | ❌ No (you can only have one repo per device) | ✅ Yes |
| Can have multiple versions in parallel (including historical ones) | ✅ Yes (unlimited number of arbitrary versions) | ✅ Yes (one per channel) | ✅ Yes (any version available in OSTree can be installed in parallel) |
| Once the application is installed, it still can be easily copied to another machine (e.g., share with a friend locally) | ✅ Yes (one app=one file; there is no “installation” so the app is in the same form at all times) | ✅ Yes (but also need to copy snaps it depends on) | ✅ Yes (you can use `flatpak create-usb` to copy to USB drive) |

#### Application Updates

| **Feature** | **AppImage** | **Snap** | **Flatpak** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Update mechanism | [AppImageUpdate](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageUpdate) | From Repo | From Repo |
| Binary delta updates | ✅ Yes (using zsync with no need to generate deltas in advance) | ✅ Yes (Only if using a private server-side service that needs to generate the deltas) | ✅ Yes (using OSTree to provide atomic updates) |
| Applications can be self-updating | ✅ Yes ([using embedded information](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageSpec/blob/master/draft.md#update-information)) | ✅ Yes | ✅ Yes |

#### Linux Distribution Support

| **Feature** | **AppImage** | **Snap** | **Flatpak** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Earliest Ubuntu Supported | Ubuntu 10.04 | Ubuntu 14.04 | Ubuntu 16.04 |
| Earliest OpenSUSE Supported | OpenSUSE 11.3 | Leap 42.2 | Leap 42.1 |
| Earliest Fedora Supported | Fedora 12 | Fedora 24 | Fedora 23 |
| Earliest Debian Supported | Debian 6 | Debian 9 | Debian 9 |
| Earliest CentOS Supported | CentOS 6 | CentOS 7.6 | CentOS 7 |
| Runs on Ubuntu out-of-the-box | ✅ Yes | ✅ Yes | ❌ No |
| Runs on OpenSUSE out-of-the-box | ✅ Yes | ❌ No | tbc |
| Runs on Fedora out-of-the-box | ✅ Yes | ❌ No | ✅ Yes |
| Runs on Debian out-of-the-box | ✅ Yes | ❌ No | tbc |
| Runs on CentOS out-of-the-box | ✅ Yes | ❌ No | ✅ Yes |
| Live systems (e.g., Live ISO, Live USB, Live CD, Live network boot) | ✅ Full | ⚠️ Partial (starting with 18.04, but it is limited by a kernel limitation and "a pain to work with, we spend almost zero time with that" according to a Canonical developer) | ⚠️ [Partial](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak.github.io/issues/303) (Session must be restarted for exports to be picked up) |
| Can run on Chrome OS (Crostini) | ✅ Yes (Chrome OS 73) | ✅ Yes (Chrome OS 73) | ✅ Yes |

#### Objectives and governance

| **Feature** | **AppImage** | **Snap** | **Flatpak** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Independent from any particular distribution maker | ✅ Yes (a community project) | ❌ No (a Canonical initiative) | ✅ Yes ([a community project](https://flatpak.org/about/)) |
| Independent from domination by any company’s business case | ✅ Yes | ❌ No (central to Canonical’s business) | ❌ No |
| Made to decrease distributions’ influence on the desktop Linux ecosystem as central gatekeepers | ✅ Yes | ❌ No | ✅ Yes ([Everyone can host his / her own repo](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/hosting-a-repository.html)) |
| Made to empower application developers and end users | ✅ Yes | ✅ Yes [[1](https://snapcraft.io/)] | ✅ Yes [[1](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/introduction.html)] |
| Working to unify the Desktop Linux Platform rather than continuing to split the user base into different distribution ecosystems | ✅ Yes (by [pointing out the core issues](https://gitlab.com/probono/platformissues) that need to be solved together) | ❌ No (effectively placing another distribution's base snap over the underlying distribution) | ❌ No (effectively placing a Yocto distribution over whatever underlying distribution) |

#### Application Size

| **Feature** | **AppImage** | **Snap** | **Flatpak** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Application storage on disk remains compressed at all times | ✅ yes | ✅ yes | ❌ No (server-side is compressed, client-side is not) [[1](https://ostree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/formats/)] |  |
| Applications use much less disk space than "traditionally installed" ones | ✅ yes | ✅ yes | tbd |
| **Example:** LibreOffice download size ([source](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2019/06/comparing-libreoffice-62-versions-appimage-flatpak-snap.html)) | ~248 MByte | 463 MByte [July 2020 update] | 543 MByte |
| Before downloading, know exactly the size to be downloaded and stored on disk | ✅ Yes (One app = one file) | ❌ No [Does not take platform snaps into account [[1](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/get-snap-package-and-dependencies-size-before-installing/19135/3?u=galgalesh)]] | ❌ [Can only estimate worst case due to de-duplication](https://twitter.com/Sesivany/status/1084022663402713088) |

#### Execution speed

| **Feature** | **AppImage** | **Snap** | **Flatpak** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LibreOffice start time ([source](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2019/06/comparing-libreoffice-62-versions-appimage-flatpak-snap.html)) | 3 seconds | 13 seconds | 7 seconds |

#### Package Format

| **Feature** | **AppImage** | **Snap** | **Flatpak** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| File format is standardized through an official standards body | ❌ No (but interested in it once the format is stabilized) | ✅ Yes (Created by the Snap format TOB[[1](https://medium.com/elementaryos/weve-joined-the-snap-format-tob-e1e46968faef)]) | ❌ No (although experimental OCI support exists) |
| Conceptually inspired by | [macOS .app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1) inside [.dmg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image) (tracing back to NeXT); [Rox AppDir](http://rox.sourceforge.net/desktop/AppDirs.html) | [Click](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/click.1.html) (Ubuntu Touch packages) | [klik](https://www.linux.com/news/one-click-installation-klik) (former name of AppImage) |

#### Project Codebase

| **Feature** | **AppImage** | **Snap** | **Flatpak** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Contributors can avoid signing CLAs | ✅ Yes | ❌ No | ✅ Yes |
| Developed since | 2004 (then called [klik](https://www.linux.com/news/one-click-installation-klik)) | 2010 (predecessor called Click Packages) | 2013 (predecessors called [Glick](https://people.gnome.org/%7Ealexl/glick/) [Glick2](https://people.gnome.org/%7Ealexl/glick2/), and [xdg-app](https://github.com/alexlarsson/xdg-app)) |

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that this chart is built from an AppImage perspective.  Meaning, the default feature set is AppImage's feature set, and the others are compared to its features.  That gives a biased edge to AppImage.  It's also somewhat out of date.  For instance, Snap added theme support this fall.

Comment: @Dan: If you are in the know about Snap's added them support -- why don't you then simply edit into the chart? Also, if you know about other features which are in Snap and/or Flatpak: feel invited to amend the chart with the respective items in the AppImage wiki...

Comment: Also, dear @Dan: I do not agree with you that *"the default feature set is AppImage's feature set, and the others are compared to its features"*. How else/otherwise would you you explain the entries for item *"Individual App repositories"*?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can say that @Kurt.  Take a look at the "Objectives" section, as an example.  It shows AppImage's objectives exclusively, as if none of the other projects have any objectives.  As if only the objectives that AppImage has matter.

Comment: @Dan: Why then don't you submits edits to the original table which show the "other projects' objectives"? It's a Wiki, you know...

Comment: I do get your point - I could edit the wiki.  However, your answer is a giant image that will presumably stay as-is in perpetuity, even as the wiki changes.  I think the bias is worth mention in context to your answer for future Ask Ubuntu readers.

Comment: @Dan: I edited the answer on July 4th to insert an updated version of the screenshot from the website (exactly in order to include some modifications which happened to the wiki). Where is the problem for you in editing the original Wiki, creating a new screenshot and then suggesting a modification of this answer with the new screenshot?

Comment: // , Wow, AppImage looks great

Comment: What's missing here is the fundamental reason why Flatpaks and Snaps exist, even though AppImage existed long before. With AppImages, it's up to the developer to make sure apps work under all conditions. With Flatpaks (and Snaps too, I believe), there are underlying runtimes that mirror the state of the developer's machine, ensuring that the app works on distros with different setups.

Comment: @TinMan: I'm sure you are smart enough to re-phrase that statement/observation into a form which makes it fit into the table as an additional entry point. Put it into the original wiki, and I'll make sure to include the updated screenshot with your contribution into my answer.

Comment: Under "Application Size" you have a couple of ticks next to "Applications use much less disk space". I only have anecdotal evidence, but in my experience this is _totally_ wrong. GIMP snap is 229MB, GIMP (traditional) is 4MB. Inkscape is 182MB vs 79MB.

Comment: @aidan: (1) I think you are definitely wrong with GIMP (traditional). Maybe the mere *executable* of GIMP is only 4 MByte. But you have to count all of the files which are included into the GIMP package, plus all of the packages which GIMP directly requires (like *'gimp-data'*, *'libgimp-2.0'* etc.)  which contains quite a lot of library files as well. See for example here: https://packages.debian.org/de/jessie/gimp and here: https://packages.debian.org/de/jessie/amd64/gimp/filelist.

Comment: @aidan: (2)  While the first link has a table (scroll down completely) which confirms your number of 4 MByte for the GIMP *package*, it also says what this number is for: the *packaged, compressed* byte size. Right next to it is the number for *'Size (installed)'* which already gives 15,2 MByte. Add the respective numbers for *'gimp-data'* and *'libgimp-2.0'*, and you already consume 63 MByte of disk space. Plus, you'll need to put more packages into place in order to get a working GIMP installation....

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Ok, so my numbers were a bit off, but how can a program packaged up with all its dependencies be smaller than the same program sharing dependencies with everything else on the host OS?

Comment: @aidan: The secret is that it is *compressed* on disk and it ***remains*** compressed on disk while it runs in RAM. 'Classical' package management systems ship software also compresssed, but only on shipment. The installation process places the files on disk *uncompressed*, hence taking much more disk space.

Comment: @aidan: Trust me, the numbers in the table are correct (in the sense of "roughly", "approximately" -- not necessarily to the last byte).

Comment: I think this is a more balanced comparison between the 3: [Comparison: Snap vs Flatpak vs AppImage](https://linuxhint.com/snap_vs_flatpak_vs_appimage/). It mentioned more about the reason behind the design of Snap and Flatpak (which AppImage didn't addressed in the first place). It also mentioned the advantage of AppImage.

Comment: there is site tracking total number of snaps here: https://snapstats.org/

Answer (score 91):

**Snaps** were created by Canonical for Ubuntu. The main advantages of snaps are:

- Independence on dependencies - all libraries and dependencies are included in the package. This also allows to have more versions of the same program.
- Sandboxing - snaps are using modified AppArmor to sandbox the applications
- Delta updates - snaps should also allow delta updates

The main drawback of snaps is that software can only use libraries included in its package. This is a potential security risk as the author of the package needs to keep all libraries patched and updated.

Snaps can currently run in Ubuntu, Arch Linux, Fedora, Linux Mint, CentOS, and Gentoo. They are also used in Ubuntu Touch. They are designed for desktops, servers, phones, IoT, and routers.

**Flatpak** has the same advantages as snaps. However, it uses Namespaces instead of AppArmour for sandboxing. The main difference is that Flatpaks can both use libraries included in the package and shared libraries from another Flatpak.

The developer of Flatpak is the Red Hat employee Alexander Larsson. Flatpak software is currently available in Arch Linux, Debian, Fedora, Mageia, Solus and Ubuntu. It is focused on desktops only.

**AppImages** are developed by Simon Peter. As in snaps or Flatpak, the package includes all libraries necessary to run the program. AppImage programs are not sandboxed and they don't require root rights to run. According to website of the project, AppImages should run on Arch Linux, Centos, Debian, Fedora, OpenSUSE, Red Hat Linux and Ubuntu.

Comment: Solus has announced [support for flatpak](https://itsfoss.com/solus-flatpak-package/) in Jan 2017

Comment: They all should have just built upon appimage. Instead of re-inventing the same ideology and introducing fragmentation and confusions. Also note that since these portable packages have all the libraries, they will be considerably heavier in size compared to an app using shared libraries installed via apt or .deb.  If you must know which is more popular, flatpak is currently beating snaps.

Comment: @magma, considering [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/962073/349837), do you know how AppImage and Flatpak packages get updated (manually [like `snap refresh`](https://askubuntu.com/a/762435/349837) or automátically)?

Comment: @answerSeeker: your comment about the portable packages being *"considerably heavier in size compared to an app using shared libraries installed via apt or .deb"* isn't necessarily backed up by the real life facts. AppImages and Snaps are compressed into SquashFS images (not true for Flatpak). They are never extracted onto disk, not even during run-time. AppImages, when running, self-mount themselves onto a temporarily created mountpoint in *`/tmp/.mount_<random-chars>`* and run from there -- still compressed! See the numbers for the LibreOffice example in screenshot of my answer below...

Comment: @PabloBianchi: newer AppImages (of the more recent *'type 2'* variety) can have a builtin update mechanism. This downloads a binary delta diff from the original AppImage location, saving in download size and time, once a new version is available and after the user indicated s/he wanted it. The tools [*`appimageupdatetool`* (CLI) and *`AppImageUpdate-Qt`* (GUI)](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageUpdate/releases) help with this.

Comment: I also like the Snap store and the installation statistics it provides for the developer (where your app is being used, which versions are installed on which version of Ubuntu etc etc).

Comment: // , Looks like a case of Not Invented Here. :(

Comment: Linux Mint actually [dropped support for Snap](https://www.zdnet.com/article/linux-mint-dumps-ubuntu-snap/) and went with flatpak.

Comment: @Chris, spectre has nothing to do with using shared libraries but running on same CPU.

Comment: flatpack was actually introduced a few months before snap, for those wondering who invented what when. It appears they were invented simultaneously for different reasons. Flatpack was not a new technology, my team implemented something similar in the 00's using the same technique (namespaces) but I couldn't get management to open source it so that company died. Namespaces exist everywhere, snap with its dependency on AppArmor is harder to move to other distributions.

Comment: two corrections: (1) snaps are not currently used in ubuntu touch, (2) there are now base snaps, so snaps can share dependencies, one side effect of this is that snaps can be smaller than traditional installs

Comment: "*why reinvent the wheel?*" They don't. It's like saying "GM does cars, why does Toyota reinvent the wheel?" (!pun) I've tried the 3 (for Gimp), and in terms of a) package availability and b) packages info, interactivity, intuitiveness, I see a clear winner: **flatpak**. snap is not far behind, and appimage is last (it might have some interesting features, but the update process, the "finding", the versioning... not for me).

Answer (score 26):

do not forgot the main thing, is it Open source ?

### AppImage

Open source Client ✅ Yes
Open source Server ✅ Yes

### Snap

Open source Client ✅ Yes
Open source Server ❌ No

### Flatpak

Open source Client ✅ Yes
Open source Server ✅ Yes

Comment: The snap store is not open-source, there were some attempted implementations but no current working ones. Please see https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/external-repositories/1760 for the very lengthy discussion on this general topic regarding the server side of desktop snap apps.

Answer (score 24):

I have found an interesting performance (CPU+Memory) comparison for these packaging systems.

**VLC**

[image: VLC]

**LibreOffice**
[image]

**Gimp**

[image]

Source:
https://verummeum.com/portable-package-formats/

Comment: This would be much easier to read if the scales were uniform.

Comment: Unluckily in my source only these plctures were available.

Comment: Also would be good to add a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several flatpaks running, the filesystem does not work properly.
For example, if I have Openscad and Flashprint open, I can write to disk(s) from Openscad, but not from Flashprint. In Snap there seems to be no problemos.