# How should I install this program? Which package type is better?

Tags: snap, appimage

I am concerned about something. I would like to install a Password manager called [KeepassXC](https://keepassxc.org/), it's a free and open source community maintained version of KeepassX. I am debating whether to use the `.AppImage` or the `.snap` package for the installation process found on their downloads page.

[image: Screenshot 1]

https://keepassxc.org/download

I've successfully downloaded and verified the `.AppImage` package. I thought I remember seeing an article that said that `.snap` packages are automatically verified when downloaded and installed on your system. Is this true? I understand that `.AppImage` packages do not require root access to run. Snap packages however do. I also heard that `.snap` packages are dying and are not very popular since Unity 8 died. Which one is more secure? Does Canonical maintain and review `.snap` packages? Which one is better in your opinion? I have barely used both of these. I've only downloaded and used a `.AppImage` and `.snap` package once so I'm not too familiar or an expert when it comes to these types of packages. I would like to know the difference and pros and cons of these two types of packages security wise. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Good question there. Also waiting for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snap is the future of Ubuntu packaging, it has the fetures you would expect form an apt package install, like updates, system intigration etc...

App Image is very diffrent, it is desinged for portability and can run on any Linux by simply making it executable and then you can move it between OS and it should work, as it is self contained. However, it will not auto update.

So, for you, it comes down to, do you want a full install, or something portable you can move around at will without reinstalling.

For security, both are secure equally, as far as format goes, the format makes little diffrence for this, it is about where you get them from. One benifit snap has here is that you can get it from the Ubuntu repos, providing it is supplied there and it will be varifiyed, in the same way apt is, this is true for your package.

Read about app image [here](https://appimage.org/)

Read about snap [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy)

Answer (score 2):

If you install the snap, you'll get automatic updates whenever the upstream developer pushes a new version to the store. I don't believe appimages auto-update.