# "gtk-warning **: cannot open display: :0" while trying to launch ElectronPlayer

Tags: snap

I am using Ubuntu 21.04 and I just installed ElectronPlayer but it is not launching. So, I tried to launch it with terminal by typing `electronplayer` but it gave me error

```
gtk-warning **: 01:10:18.304: cannot open display: :0
```

And if I do `sudo electronplayer`, I get

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your snap package.

To update snap package follow these steps from [Zygmunt's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/762435) on [How can I update all Snap packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760823)

> ```
> sudo snap refresh
> ```
>
> Will do this. It is part of `snapd` 2.0.8, which landed 2016-06-13 in
> `xenial-updates`.
>
> ```
> snap refresh --list
> ```
>
> Only lists the updates without refreshing the packages.
>
> ```
> snap info <snap name>
> ```
>
> Can show which versions are available for a particular package.

Comment: thank you i just did that and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential fix for this error as of Ubuntu 22.04 that worked for me.

- Be sure to remove the stable version with:
  `sudo snap remove electronplayer`
- Open the Ubuntu Software app and find ElectronPlayer.
- On the "Source" dropdown at the upper right area, select the
  latest/beta version 2.0.8 (or whatever the most recent version is).

That should work.

Alternatively, you can get the [Version 2.0.8](https://github.com/oscartbeaumont/ElectronPlayer/releases/tag/v2.0.8-rc4) package and install it yourself. Or check [ElectronPlayer release](https://github.com/oscartbeaumont/ElectronPlayer/releases) for the most recent version if this is outdated.

---

From the [ElectronPlayer release](https://github.com/oscartbeaumont/ElectronPlayer/releases):

> If you installed any previous versions of 2.0.8 please update to this
> one as the previous ones have problems due to me releasing them in a
> rush.

Also take a look at [The Pain of Widevine](https://github.com/oscartbeaumont/ElectronPlayer#the-pain-of-widevine) in the README. It may be a good reason to use the most recent beta version if stable is not working for you.