# System update misses things

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, software-center, snap

Why is it that if you run a system update or use dist-upgrade you're still left with things needing updating?

For example if you run a full system update and than open software updater it says "your system is up to date."

But if you open the software center and check for updates, there are still packages listed requiring update.

These sometimes include:

- shared gnome ubuntu stack
- gtk common theme
- snapd
- snap store
- core 18

Why are these not covered by the the system update?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I update all Snap packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760823/how-can-i-update-all-snap-packages)

Answer (score 3):

The programs you mention are snap packages. Running the command `sudo apt dist-upgrade` only upgrades `.deb` packages, but not snap packages.

Snap packages should upgrade themselves eventually, but if you want to force an upgrade run this command:

```
sudo snap refresh
```

Comment: I see, thank you for that. Where are snaps stored?

Comment: Snaps are located in `/snap`, and userdata in `~/snap`