# Impossible upgrade core 22: snap has no updates available

Tags: updates

when I open Ubuntu Software in the Updates panel I see "core 22 20230725", but when I click update I got the message in the title.
The exact message I got is: "Impossibile aggiornare core 22: snap has no updates available", because it's in Italian, so I don't know exaclty which is the message in English.
I've tried "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade", which worked correctly but did not change the situation.
I've Ubuntu 22.04
Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

After re-installing ubuntu desktop (sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop) and a reboot, the problem disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the system monitor and closing Snap Store, then from the terminal enter:
`sudo snap start` and then `sudo snap refresh` ([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760823/how-can-i-update-all-snap-packages/762435#762435)).

Let me know if it works!

sim.dll

Comment: Thanks but I've solved just some minute before your post.